# My phpUnit laravel test doesn't recognize my imported class using namespaces

Tags: php, laravel

When I run the command "php artisan test" to execute my unit tests inside my Keycloak service class, I receive the following error:

```
Class "App\Services\Keycloak" not found

  at tests\Unit\KeycloakTest.php:23
     19▕         $base_realm = env('KEYCLOAK_REALM');
     20▕         $base_client_id = env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID');
     21▕         $base_client_secret= env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET');
     22▕
  ➜  23▕         $keycloak = new \App\Services\Keycloak($base_url, $base_realm, $base_client_id, $base_client_secret);
     24▕
     25▕
     26▕
     27▕         $this->keycloak = $keycloak->getAdminToken();

  1   tests\Unit\KeycloakTest.php:23
```

I already doublechecked the path of my file and the namespaces of my classes but none seems to have worked

Here is my KeycloakTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;


use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class KeycloakTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     */

    protected $keycloak;

    protected function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
        // Add your setup code here
        $base_url = env('KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL');
        $base_realm = env('KEYCLOAK_REALM');
        $base_client_id = env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID');
        $base_client_secret= env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET');

        $keycloak = new \App\Services\Keycloak($base_url, $base_realm, $base_client_id, $base_client_secret);

    

        $this->keycloak = $keycloak->getAdminToken();
    }
        
    


    public function test_get_token(): void
    {
        // Mocking user credentials
        $username = 'test';
        $password = 'Test123@!';
        $email = 'dummy@outlook.com';
        $response = $this->keycloak->getToken($username, $password, $email);

        // Assert that the response is an array
        $this->assertIsArray($response);

        // Assert that the response has a key named 'access_token'
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('access_token', $response);
    }

}
```

And here is the start of my keycloak.php file:

```
<?

namespace App\Services;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Exception;

class Keycloak {
```

I have tried already looking on the internet and checked my composer.json as well

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/",
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

My keycloak.php file is on the path app/Services/keycloak.php

Comment: `app/Services/keycloak.php` is not what your file should be called. Class names are case sensitive.

Comment: And `<?` is not how to start a PHP file

Comment: I misspelled the Keycloak.php and you are right about the <? I was so focused in trying to discover an advanced problem that I forgot to review the most basic errors. Thank you